# "Straight" version of an image with alpha channel

Tags: css, opengl-es, shader

So I'm working on a shader for the upcoming CSS shader spec. I’m building something specifically targeted toward professional video product, and I need to separate out the alpha channel (as luminance, which I’ve done successfully), and a “straight” version of the image, which has no alpha channel.

Example: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/shadertest.html (only works with [fancy adobe webkit browser](https://github.com/adobe/webkit))

I’m so close, just trying to figure out the last shader.

Here’s an example of what I’d expect to see. (This is from a Targa file)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/Randalls%20Mess.png – the fill (what I haven’t figured out)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/Randalls%20Mess%20Alpha.png – the key (aka alpha which I have figured out)

(The final, in case you're curious: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/final.png )

I thought it'd be a matrix transform, but I'm thinking now that i've tried more and more, it's going to be something more complex than a matrix transform. Am I sadly correct? And if so, how would I even get started attacking this problem?

Comment: I'm not at all experienced with video processing, so maybe I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what you mean by the "straight" image. Are you referring to the RGB color values without alpha modulation? (Non-Premultiplied?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG filters are now the way to pull this off in Chrome.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/alphaCanvases.html

It's still early though, and CSS animations are only supported in the Canary build currently.

Answer (score 1):

In your shader, I presume you have some piece of code that samples the textures similar to the following, yes?

```
vec4 textureColor = texture2D(texture1, texCoord);
```

`textureColor` at that point contains 4 values: the Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha channels, each ranging from 0 to 1. You can access each of these colors separately:

```
float red = textureColor.r;
float alpha = textureColor.a;
```

or by using a technique known as "swizzling" you can access them in sets:

```
vec3 colorChannels = textureColor.rgb;
vec2 alphaAndBlue = textureColor.ab;
```

The color values that you get out of this should not be premultipied, so the alpha won't have any effect unless you want it to.

It's actually a very common to use this to do things like packing the specular level for a texture into the alpha channel of the diffuse texture:

```
float specularLevel = textureColor.a;
float lightValue = lightFactor + (specularFactor * specularLevel); // Lighting factors calculated from normals
gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * lightValue, 1.0); // 1.0 gives us a constant alpha
```

Given the flexibility of shaders any number of effects are possible that use and abuse various combinations of color channels, and as such it's difficult to say the exact algorithm you'll need. Hopefully that gives you an idea of how to work with the color channels separately, though.

Comment: It appears due to some timing attack potentials, gl_FragColor isn't supported. My shader uses css_ColorMatrix.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out a workable solution.

Comment: Hm... okay. That's different then. I'm not familiar with CSS shaders, sadly. I've tweaked the question tags to hopefully garner attention from someone with the right skillset, but if I find out anything on this I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, according to one of the [adobe guys](http://blattchat.com/2012/05/30/webkit-filter-shaders-oh-my/), this is not possible in CSS shader language since the matrix transform is only able to transform existing values, and not add a 'bias' vector.

The alternative, which I'm exploring now, is to use SVG filters.